# slice 2d tensor specified by index tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, tensorflow, slice

I have a 2d tensor and I want to extract few starting elements from each row.
I have column index (for each row) upto which elements must be captured.
Note that column index is different for different rows.
Following example makes it concreate:
2d tensor is:

```
[[4 2 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [4 4 4 5 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [4 4 4 4 6 4 4 8 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [1 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [3 9 4 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]  
 [3 9 9 6 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

and the index array is:

```
[4 7 7 7 9 7 7 7 7 7]
```

How to get following array from above index array:

```
[[4 2 4 4 ]  
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ]  
 [4 4 4 5 4 4 4]  
 [4 4 1 4 4 4 4]  
 [4 4 4 4 6 4 4 8 8]  
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 ]  
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 ]  
 [1 9 9 9 9 9 9 ]  
 [3 9 4 9 9 9 9 ]  
 [3 9 9 6 9 9 9 ]]
```

Comment: The problem is the output that you describe cannot be an array, because each slice has a different size. What exactly would you like to get? You could have a `list` of arrays or a `tf.TensorArray`, but those are not as useful as a proper `tf.Tensor`. How are you planning to use the output?

Comment: I want to convert this tensor to sparse tensor but I cannot do this because some of the ending elements in the row are also present in the middle of the row. So I want to extract starting elements specified by the index array and convert resulting tensor to sparse tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get that as a sparse tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Example data
data = [[4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 9, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 9, 9, 6, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
sizes = [4, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Input data
    data_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
    sizes_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    shape = tf.shape(data_ph)
    # Make coordinates grid
    ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(shape[0]), tf.range(shape[1]), indexing='ij')
    # Make mask for values
    mask = jj < tf.expand_dims(sizes_ph, 1)
    # Take values and coordinates
    sp_values = tf.boolean_mask(data_ph, mask)
    sp_ii = tf.boolean_mask(ii, mask)
    sp_jj = tf.boolean_mask(jj, mask)
    # Make sparse index
    sp_idx = tf.cast(tf.stack([sp_ii, sp_jj], axis=1), tf.int64)
    # Make sparse tensor
    sp_tensor = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(sp_idx, sp_values, tf.cast(shape, tf.int64))
    # Convert back to dense for testing
    sp_to_dense = tf.sparse.to_dense(sp_tensor)
    # Test
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sp_to_dense_value = sess.run(sp_to_dense, feed_dict={data_ph: data, sizes_ph: sizes})
        print(sp_to_dense_value)
```

Output:

```
[[4 2 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 4 4 5 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 4 1 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 4 4 4 6 4 4 8 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 9 4 9 9 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 9 9 6 9 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

It is not absolutely ideal, since it requires operating with the full grid of coordinates. In NumPy you would probably be able to generate the indices first and then select only the values you want from the dense tensor, but I'm not sure that's possible with TensorFlow.

Comment: just one thing to clarify. does tensorflow support these operations for training neural network in following scenario: 'data' tensor is output of network1 and 'sp_tensor' is used to calculate loss from network2 along with output from network2. Since these operations are not differentiable, I doubt that training of network1 and network2 will occur properly.